# Install impresspages to localhost - problems with db connection

Tags: php, impresspages

When i try to install impresspages on localhost in Database installation i see this:

> Can't connect to database.

I try to solve this problem by installing it on hosting(its install with no problems) and then transfer it to localhost with all database, and i edit config file. And when i go to home page i saw this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Ip\Exception\Db' in C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\ServiceLocator.php:258 Stack trace: #0 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Db.php(28): Ip\Db->getConnection() #1 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\ServiceLocator.php(258): Ip\Db->__construct() #2 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\ServiceLocator.php(226): Ip\ServiceLocator::loadService('db') #3 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Functions.php(379): Ip\ServiceLocator::db() #4 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Internal\Plugins\Model.php(316): ipDb() #5 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Internal\Plugins\Service.php(9): Ip\Internal\Plugins\Model::getActivePluginNames() #6 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Dispatcher.php(140): Ip\Internal\Plugins\Service::getActivePluginNames() #7 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Application.php(153): Ip\Dispatcher->_bindApplicationEvents() #8 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Application.php(319): Ip\Application->_handleOnlyRequest(Object(Ip\Request), Array, false) #9 C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\Application.php(413): Ip\Application->handleRequest(Object(Ip\Request), Ar in C:\www\Apache2\htdocs\ip\Ip\ServiceLocator.php on line 258

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL is installed and runs normally? Do you have any other projects on localhost that successfully connects to database?

Comment: Joomla, wordpress is works normally

Comment: ImpressPages does nothing specific regarding connection to the database. Just triplecheck the database credentials. I've seen cases where people had to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost or vice verse.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the MySQL extension for PHP is not installed or enabled. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php for more information.